# VM118:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
public function follow($followerID, $user_id){
    $this->create('follow', array('sender' => $user_id, 'receiver'=> $followID, 'followOn'=> date("Y:M:D H:i:s")));
    $this->addFollowCount($followID, $user_id);
    $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` =:followID');
    $stmt->execute(array("followID" => $followID));
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
public function unfollow($followerID, $user_id){
    $this->delete('follow', array('sender' => $user_id, 'receiver'=> $followID));
    $this->addFollowCount($followID, $user_id);
    $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` =:followID');
    $stmt->execute(array("followID" => $followID));
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data);
}

public function addFollowCount($followerID, $user_id){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `following` = `following` + 1 WHERE `user_id` = :user_id; UPDATE `users` SET `followers` = `followers`+ 1 WHERE  `user_id`= :followID ");
    $stmt->execute(array("user_id" => $user_id, "followID" => $followID));  
}
public function removeFollowCount($followerID, $user_id){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `following` = `following` - 1 WHERE `user_id` = :user_id; UPDATE `users` SET `followers` = `followers`- 1 WHERE  `user_id`= :followID ");
    $stmt->execute(array("user_id" => $user_id, "followID" => $followID));  
}
```

Here is my AJAX code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['unfollow']) && !empty($_POST['unfollow'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $followID = $_POST['unfollow'];
    $getFromU->unfollow($followID, $user_id);

}
if (isset($_POST['follow']) && !empty($_POST['follow'])) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $followID = $_POST['follow'];
    $getFromU->follow($followID, $user_id);

}
```

> VM262:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()
>   at Object.success (follow.js:7)
>   at j (jquery.min.js:2)
>   at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>   at x (jquery.min.js:4)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)

where i am gettinh wrong and i am using jquery.min.js lib1.1

Comment: Your JSON is actually HTML? Have you checked the content?

Comment: The error means that the response isn't actually JSON, but instead XML or HTML, usually caused by an error on the server side. Check what the actual responseText is.